# What changes should I have to implement in my .htaccess if I want to allow specific URL but prevent on all others?

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?site1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?site2\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

The above code is doing the opposite for me. I want to a site1 and site2 but prevent all others.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your .htaccess rules file in following manner. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ! ^https?://(?:www\.)?(?:site1|site2)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: @Iqbal Hussain, Did this work out for you?